# Hilt, Inject types with multiple scopes

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm doing dependency injection with dagger hilt. Most of my types are singletons so I have my hilt module installed in the `SingletonComponent` like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object MyAppModule {
   @Provides
    fun provideUserService(service: UserServiceImpl): UserService {
        return service
    }
    // And a bunch of other "provides" functions exactly like this one.
}
```

As for type declarations I go like this:

```
@Singleton
class UserServiceImpl @Inject constructor(/* dependencies go here */): UserService {}
```

It all worked as expected until I needed to inject an activity class in my LocationService using the `@ActivityContext` and as you know that one can't be a singleton. So I made the location service `@ActivityScoped`

```
@ActivityScoped
class LocationProviderImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext private val activity: ComponentActivity
)
```

but putting a provides function for this one in the module above breaks the app with this error

```
MyApplication_HiltComponents.java:134: error: [Dagger/IncompatiblyScopedBindings] com.example.app.di.MyApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC scoped with @Singleton may not reference bindings with different scopes:
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MyApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      @dagger.hilt.android.scopes.ActivityScoped class com.example.app.services.LocationServiceImpl
```

So I thought maybe I should put provides for location service in a separate module that was installed in the activity component...

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class MyActivityModule {
    @Provides
    fun locationService(locationService: LocationServiceImpl): LocationService {
        return locationService
    }
}
```

And it only got me a different error:

```
MyApplication_HiltComponents.java:134: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.app.services.LocationService cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MyApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.example.app.services.LocationService is injected at
          com.example.app.viewmodels.MapScreenViewModel(�, locationService)
      com.example.app.viewmodels.MapScreenViewModel is injected at
          com.example.app.viewmodels.MapScreenViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.example.app.di.MyApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.example.app.di.MyApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.example.app.di.MyApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

I sure do have a `@Provides-annotated method` so I guess it's ignoring the `MyActivityModule` that I just declared.

So I was wondering if anyone knows the right way to go about this problem.

Comment: You cannot inject ActivityScoped in Singleton because ActivityScoped has a shorter lifecycle https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html

Comment: @IR42 It doesn't go in a singleton, it goes in a viewmodel but I guess your point still stands. I guess I can't have an activity instance in my service after all. will need to find another way to ask for permissions.